# How to download PDF file through Android Web View?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have an android web view which works perfectly fine.
I added the below code to download the PDF file.

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Although it works perfectly fine on the web,

But in Android Webview App :

- It gives me an in-app notification of "Downloading File"
- Shows the loader for a while
- Then a notification on the notification bar says "Download Unsuccessful" from Download Manager

- Please note that I have also given permission in Manifest as well.

For the full code of [MainActivity.java](https://ideone.com/aSw33L) please refer to the link.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a _"PHP DOM-generated PDF file"_? Do you simply mean a PDF file that was generated using PHP or do you mean something else? Also, unless the issue is with your PHP code (which you then need to add and explain the issue), please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: Thanks for the PHP tag. (removed it). And yes, I m generating a PDF using PHP **dompdf**

Comment: When posting a question, it's important to only add relevant information. If you've made sure that your endpoint for getting the file from PHP works (which should be the first thing you test), then only say: "How to download file through Android Web View". The more things you add to your question (specially the title), might make people skip it since they think the question is about something else. It's for you to get the best help possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This guy from youtube solved it for me.

```
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

But the issue is that the app is redirecting to chrome to load the URL and letting me download the file. Is there any other way to load the URL in the background and download the file?

Hope it helps someone..

Comment: Actually, I'm passing a link to download the pdf from the site. And it's default redirecting to chrome taking that link. In general, I don't want the users to see the link in the first place. Is there any way? Can you please help me out on this?

Comment: This is not an answer , it still open a browser not open the pdf in the web view